# How do single click expire links work from context of reset password

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, hyperlink, password-recovery

I am designing & developing **"Reset Password"** form, where user provides username/email address so that application will send a link in a email for the user to  click and type a new password. My interest is all about that link, How should i go ahead doing these jobs( I am not looking for answers that will be based on opinion but rather industry practices, steps that worked for your applications).

- Make sure link is not bookmark enabled(Don't allow him resetting the password with the same link)
- If the links also contains expiry information, What should happen if he clicks expired link

you can also help me by providing other problems i may face with current plan of execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just implemented something similar.

1. User clicks "lost password" and enters email address.
2. On submit, generate a reset code so the main password is unaffected. (should be salt hashed too). Set a timeout for using the reset code.
3. User visits change password form. Enters email, reset code, new password and confirm password. On success, clear reset code and set new password, redirect to the login page.

I decided to make the reset code as part of the url as to make it easier for the users. As for bookmarking, well, you can't protect all users like that. If they want to bookmark that page, let them. The above measures should stop them submitting anything out of line.

Comment: Since we set expiry time on reset code, what happens after reset code expires they generate another one?

Comment: You inform the user that the existing code has expired and they need to request again using the lost password form. This will be rare as most users will complete the lost password process quickly. The point is that the reset code is not always open to a second place for users to try to hack passwords.

Comment: Why would you salt+hash the reset code if it has also got a near-future expiry date?

Comment: So someone that has access to the database cannot hijack the account. That is one main reason for salting passwords/reset codes is internal security.

Answer (score 2):

On the reset form's submit you generate a random code, store it in a database(with expiry information if needed and a flag if it has been used) and include it as a parameter in the link.

The link brings the user back to the reset form where you check if the code(parameter) is in the database and has not expired or used already.

Comment: explained in short, same technique as Valamas

Answer (score 2):

The approach that I like is to create a string that looks somehow like this: [username]*[currentPassword]*[expirationDate], hash it, and then create a link that looks like: resetPassword.php?username=[username]&exp=[expirationDate]&hash=[hash]

In resetPassword.php you verify this hash with the info in the GET params + the old password you had, and if hash matches, go on with reseting the password.
This way the link will expire whenever it should expire, and it will be impossible to reset the password with that link after the password was changed.

Another approach is to store the reset password code in the database.

Comment: you mean, `if hash(username+currpass+expiry) equals hash(query string params) then reset form is shown`

Comment: More or less so. To be more precise - reconstruct the string the same way you did when you generated link(use username+expiry from query string and password from DB), hash it, and compare to hash from query string. If both match show reset form screen, otherwise show "bad link" screen.